# dispatch_after after dealloc issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, dealloc

In MyViewController in viewDidLoad I have only one call:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.isNeedToExecute = YES;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(20 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self doSomeSimpleThings];
            });
}

-(void)doSomeSimpleThings {
      if (!self.isNeedToExecute) {
           return;
      }
      // do some simple actions
}

- (void)dealloc {
     self.isNeedToExecute = NO;
}
```

After that in code I pop this view controller, so without `dispatch_after` the `dealloc` would be executed for sure.

**The questions:**

1) will the dealloc method be called in this case (when we have `dispatch_after`, that should be executed in 20 seconds)?

2) will this method `[self doSomeSimpleThings];` be executed after `dealloc`?

**Edit:**

I tried it before posting this question, and dealloc wasn't called and thought that it was strange, that's why I asked this question here.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?  Is your question really "If I run this code, what will happen?"

Comment: I would *suspect* the instance will be retained as you reference `self` within the `dispatch_async()` block, so the code will be called.  You need to set `isNeedToExecute` in a different method (like `viewDidDisappear`).

Comment: 1. doSomeSimpleThings will not called after dealloc.
2. dealloc will call only if your MyViewController will be removed from stack. So in your case it should not call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code creates a retain cycle because you reference `self` inside the block. You can break the cycle by using a weak reference to `self`. This way you also don't need the `isNeedToExecute` flag:

```
__weak id blockSelf = self;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(20 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [blockSelf doSomeSimpleThings];
});
```

After deallocation of your view controller `blockSelf` is `nil` and `doSomeSimpleThings` won't be executed.

Comment: Can you explain which retains self in the retain cycle?

Comment: @CarouselMin Isn't it obvious?

Comment: Blocks retain all variables that are referenced inside. But you are right, in this case it's not a cycle. The reference is just kept until the timer fires.

Comment: "Your current code creates a retain cycle because you reference self inside the block." NO. There is no retain cycle.

Comment: see my comment directly above yours.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) will the dealloc method be called in this case (when we have
>   dispatch_after, that should be executed in 20 seconds)?

`dealloc` will be called after there are no strong references to the object anymore. The block holds a strong reference to the object. `dispatch_after` keeps the block until after it runs. So after 20 seconds, after the block runs, there will be no more strong references, and the object can be deallocated (`dealloc` called).

> 2) will this method [self doSomeSimpleThings]; be executed after
>   dealloc?

This is backwards. In fact, when `dealloc` is called is determined by when the block (containing `[self doSomeSimpleThings]`) runs. So the answer is no, kind of by definition, because `dealloc` cannot run until it is no longer possible to run `[self doSomeSimpleThings]` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Check the definition of *dispatch_after* method. Parameters are defined as

> queue:- The queue on which to submit the block. The queue is retained by the system until the block has run to completion. This parameter cannot be NULL.
>
> block: - <......>This function perform a Block_copy and Block_release on behalf of the caller.

So basically your controller object will be retained by this queue even if you have poped it and method *doSomeSimpleThings* will be called and then *dealloc*.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but the real reason is that the *block* retains `self`.